# PHP: How to Read Text File like Notepad++

Tags: php, text, notepad++

I have a text file that contains lines of text:

[image]

When I open it in Notepad ++ It is aligned and the columns are separated with space:

[image]

Is there any way to echo this through my PHP code to give an output like Notepad++?

I've used the following code

```
 <?php

 header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

 echo  file_get_contents("MAGFLE_Greenbnk_Caraga.txt");

 ?>
```

Output:

[image]

Do I need to declare ANSII/UTF8 encoding/decoding in my code?

Your help will be very much appreciated

Comment: You need to convert newline characters to an HTML newline tag using [nl2br()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) (though that won't help with the spaces); or wrap the whole in `<pre>` tags

Comment: `echo  "<pre/>"; file_get_contents("MAGFLE_Greenbnk_Caraga.txt");`

Comment: ^ Thank You so much guys! :)

Comment: Failing that, change line feeds to end of rows, with end cell, end row, new row, new cell, and change the tabs for end cell new cell and do do it in a hidden table

Answer (score 0):

```
$handle = @fopen("myfile.txt", "r");
if($handle) 
{
    while ( ($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096) ) !== false ) 
{
    echo $buffer."\r\n";
}
    @fclose($handle);

}
```